# Find all input of td inside a TR in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How we can find all the inputs of a td inside a tr in jquery.
I have tr that will have multiple td in that td i have inputs and select so i want to get the values of the input types
Code :

```
$('div#divid tbody.tbodyClass tr.trClass').each(function() {
            $(this td).find("input:text,select").each(function() {
                textVal = this.value;
                inputName = $(this).attr("name");
                formData+='&'+inputName+'='+textVal;
            });
            InsideCount++   
        });
```

I am trying to use this td's with each but i am not able to get the values and name of the inputs.

Comment: Replace $(this td) to $(this) and textVal = this.value; to textVal = $(this).val();

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have syntax error at `$(this td)`. td should be used in find selector:

```
$(this).find("td input:text,td select").each(function() {
            textVal = this.value;
            inputName = $(this).attr("name");
            formData+='&'+inputName+'='+textVal;
        });
        InsideCount++
```

as `td`s will be the only direct child of `tr`s , you can narrow down the selector to:

```
 $(this).find("input:text,select").each(function() {
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  check updated code. move td inside find() selector.  

    $('div#divid tbody.tbodyClass tr.trClass').each(function() {
        $(this).find("td input:text,select").each(function() {
            textVal = this.value;
            inputName = $(this).attr("name");
            formData+='&'+inputName+'='+textVal;
        });
        InsideCount++   
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('tr:has(input)').each(function() {
var inputName = "";
var values = "";
$('input', this).each(function() {
inputName = inputName +","+ $(this).attr("name");
  values =  values + "," + $(this).val() 
});
});
```